Assumption in Hörmander-Mikhlin multiplier theorem
The well-known Hörmander-Mikhlin multiplier theorem is the following statement:
Let $m \in C^N(\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\})$ with $N = [n/2] + 1$ and
suppose for each multi-index $\alpha$ with $|\alpha| \leq N$, there exists a constant $c_{\alpha} > 0$ such that
$$|\partial^{\alpha} m(\xi)| \leq c_{\alpha} |\xi|^{-|\alpha|}, \quad \forall \xi \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\}.$$
Then, the Fourier multiplier operator defined by $T_mf = \mathcal{F}^{-1}[m \hat{f}]$ is a bounded operator on $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for all $1 < p < \infty$.
I am wondering if the multiplier theorem holds under the following slightly weaker assumptions: For each multi-index $\alpha$ with $|\alpha| \leq N$,
$$\sup_{\xi \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\}} |\xi^{\alpha} \partial^{\alpha}m(\xi)| < +\infty$$
or, equivalently, there exists a constant $c_{\alpha} > 0$ such that
$$|\partial^{\alpha} m(\xi)| \leq c_{\alpha} |\xi^{\alpha}|^{-1}$$
whenever $\xi^{\alpha} = \xi_1^{\alpha_1} \cdots \xi_n^{\alpha_n} \not=0$.
Any ideas are welcome.

Interesting question! Although I believe no I have no clue on how the counterexample looks like either.

Yes, I believe this slightly weaker condition is sufficient. To see this, note that in Grafakos' Classical Fourier Analysis, the proof of the Hormander-Mikhlin multiplier theorem also uses a slightly weaker assumption, which is, for any multi-index $\alpha$ with $|\alpha| \leq N$ (using the same $N$ as you defined in your question), then there exists a constant $C_\alpha > 0$ such that
\begin{equation}
 \left( \int_{R < |\xi| < 2R} |\partial^{\alpha}m(\xi)|^2\, d\xi \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \leq C_\alpha R^{\frac{n}{2} - |\alpha|} < \infty 
\end{equation}
so it suffices to show that your proposed condition implies the condition above for each multi-index $\alpha$.
For a given $R > 0$, then in $\mathbb{R}^n$, we can observe that
$$ \{\xi \in \mathbb{R}^n: R < |\xi| < 2R\} \subset \prod_{i = 1}^n \{\xi_i \in \mathbb{R} : \frac{R}{\sqrt{n}} < |\xi_i| < 2R\} := E_R$$
that is, we can replace the integrals over annuli by integrals over squares (which have a square removed from the inside). This allows us to get the following inequality:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
 \left( \int_{R < |\xi| < 2R} |\partial^{\alpha}m(\xi)|^2\, d\xi \right) &\leq \left( \int_{E_R} |\partial^{\alpha}m(\xi)|^2\, d\xi \right)\\
&= c_\alpha^2 \left( \int_{E_R} \dfrac{1}{|\xi^\alpha|^2}\, d\xi \right)\\
&= c_\alpha^2 \left( \int_{E_R} \dfrac{1}{|\xi_1|^{2\alpha_1} \cdots |\xi_n|^{2\alpha_n}}\, d\xi_1 \dots d\xi_n \right)\\
&= c_\alpha^2 \left(\int_{\frac{R}{\sqrt{n}} < |\xi_1| < 2R} \dfrac{1}{|\xi_1|^{2\alpha_1}}\, d\xi_1  \right) \cdots \left(\int_{\frac{R}{\sqrt{n}} < |\xi_n| < 2R} \dfrac{1}{|\xi_n|^{2\alpha_n}}\, d\xi_n \right) \\
&= c_\alpha^2 2^n [\xi_1^{1 - 2\alpha_1}]^{2R}_{\frac{R}{\sqrt{n}}} \cdots [\xi_n^{1 - 2\alpha_n}]^{2R}_{\frac{R}{\sqrt{n}}}\\
&= c_\alpha^2 2^n \prod_{i = 1}^n \left((2R)^{1 - 2\alpha_i} - (\frac{R}{\sqrt{n}})^{1 - 2\alpha_i} \right)\\
&= \left[c_\alpha^2 2^n  \prod_{i = 1}^n \left(2^{1 - 2\alpha_i} - (\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})^{1 - 2\alpha_i} \right) \right] R^{\sum_{i = 1}^n 1 - 2\alpha_i}\\
&= \left[c_\alpha^2 2^n  \prod_{i = 1}^n \left(2^{1 - 2\alpha_i} - (\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})^{1 - 2\alpha_i} \right) \right] R^{n - 2|\alpha|}\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
From here, all that is left to do is to observe that taking a square root will yield our desired inequality.
